# Rails Relationship Questions (categories, products, and projects)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many

I have 3 models, Categories, Products and Projects.

The goal is to get a list of all Categories that have products (category.products.count >0) and where the Project that that the Product belongs to is not marked as private.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :products
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protected

    def set_categories
        @categories = Category.joins(:products).where("products.is_product = true or       
                       products.is_loving_this = true")
        category = Category.find_by(title: "All")
        @categories.unshift(category).uniq!
    end
 end

views/layouts/_title_bar.html.haml
%nav.navbar-custom1.navbar.navbar-custom1.navbar-default.navbar-static-top{role: "navigation"}
    .container
       .col-xs-4
           %ul.nav.navbar-nav
           %ul.dropdown#dropdown_title_bar
               %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", href: "#", type: "button"}
                   Products
                   %b.caret
           %ul.dropdown-menu{"aria-labelledby" => "dropdown-menu", role: "menu"}
               - @categories.each do |c|
                   - if c.products.count > 0 || c.title == "All"
                       %li= link_to c.title, category_path(c)
```

The code above gives me a dropdown list of all Categories where category.products.count > 0 but I can't figure out how to only get products where the product.project.private == false.

Can anyone guide me on how to add that?
I thought about doing 2 loops, but it seems messy.

```
- @categories.each do |c|
    - if c.products.count > 0 || c.title == "All"          
        - c.products.each do |product| 
            - if product.project && product.project.private == false
                       %li= link_to c.title, category_path(c)
```

The last catch is that sometimes products don't have a project, which is why I added the first if statement
    - if product.project && product.project.private == false

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you come up with some scopes to help out with this query.

```
app/models/product.rb
# BTW, can you come up with a better name for this? When is a product not a product?
scope :is_product, -> { where(is_product: true )}
scope :is_loving_this, -> { where(is_loving_this: true) }
scope :is_public, -> { include(:project).where(projects: { private: false }) }
```

Then your query can look something like:

```
app/models/category.rb
def self.active_categories
  category_ids = Products.is_public.is_product.is_loving_this.map(&:category_id)
  Category.find(category_ids)      
end
```

Note, this is all untested, so please write some tests to verify... :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a scope, you can do it with a subquery (Rails does it in 2 separate queries):

```
scope :wanted_categories, -> { Category.joins(:products).where("
                   (products.is_product = true or       
                   products.is_loving_this = true) and products.id in (?)", 
                   Product.joins(:projects).where("projects.private 
                   = false").pluck(:id) }
```

Rails first runs the subquery and grabs the list of product ids who's project is not private, then uses the list to populate a sql set (note the parenthesis around the question mark) for the main query.

This approach works smoothly when you are looking for values that ARE `IN` a set, but if instead you need to use it with `NOT IN`, then there will be a caveat:
If the subquery returns no elements, rails will populate the sql set with `NULL`, which means nothing will match, `products.id in (NULL)` and `products.id not in (NULL)` both return nothing. In that case, you would want to turn the subquery into a scope and make your main scope conditional and make it run only if the subquery returns something. E.g:

```
class Product
scope :of_public_project, -> { joins(:projects).where("projects.private = false") }

class Category
scope :wanted_categories, -> { joins(:products).where("(products.is_product = true
                   or products.is_loving_this = true) and products.id not in
                   (?)", Product.of_public_project.pluck(:id) if Product.of_public_project.any?}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason,

Using your suggestions worked however, loving_this never belongs to a project so I can't chain all the methods together as you suggest.

I have to separate them like so:

```
def get_categories
    category_ids = Product.is_public.product_type.map(&:category_id)
    loving_this_ids = Product.loving_this_type.map(&:category_id)
    @categories = Category.find(category_ids, loving_this_ids)
end
```

Do you think this is ok? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Minor thing, but you can also replace `map(&:category_id)` with `pluck(:category_id)` which should reduce the amount of data transferred from the DB. One other thing you can try is (not sure if will work): `@categories = Category.scoped.merge(Product.is_public.product_type).merge(Product.loving_this_type)`